# How to filter data in Rails client side without AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I currently use AJAX and a select_tag to load filtered records from my database and render a partial that displays this data as a list.

However, as I do not really need AJAX at this point I was asking myself what would be the best way to load all data from the database and then do the filtering client-side (including re-rendering the partial after the user did the selection)?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated as I was looking for solutions now the last few hours but did not find anything useful.

Comment: That's where client-side frameworks shine. Angular, Ember, React and 50 others. Look into a couple of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://datatables.net/
It has option for using ajax to populate data on the go, or load all data first hand and then filter it in front end